MUI ThemeProvider with NextJS 14 (App Router) Failing
I have a NextJS app running with material ui's component library. I tried to integrate the ThemeProvider at the root of the project (/app/layout.tsx) but it throws seemingly unrelated errors at runtime.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'duration')
Call Stack: 
duration
node_modules\@mui\material\Fade\Fade.js (30:30)
etc...

src/app/layout.tsx
import React from "react";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import MainHeader from "./NavBar";
import FeedbackProvider from "@/components/providers/FeedbackProvider";
import UserProvider from "@/components/providers/UserProvider";
import { lightTheme } from "@/lib/themeOptions";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import { AppRouterCacheProvider } from "@mui/material-nextjs/v13-appRouter";

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
        </head>
        <body>
          <AppRouterCacheProvider>
            <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
              <FeedbackProvider>
                <UserProvider>
                  <MainHeader />
                  {children}
                </UserProvider>
              </FeedbackProvider>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </AppRouterCacheProvider>
        </body>
      </html>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

package.json
 "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.8",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.15",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.16",
    "@mui/material-nextjs": "^5.15.11",
    "@mui/system": "^5.15.15",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.17.0",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.11.0",
    "@supabase/ssr": "^0.1.0",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.39.8",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "fund": "^1.0.0",
    "next": "^14.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "server-only": "^0.0.1",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
}

I have tried:

Following material ui's example: https://mui.com/material-ui/integrations/nextjs/#app-router
Updating nextjs from 14.0.1 -> 14.2.3 and updating/reinstalling material ui packages one at a time
Calling the ThemeProvider directly inside the layout.tsx and also abstracting it to a client component and importing that into layout.tsx
Wrapping a single client page in the ThemeProvider and it threw the same error but for a different Material UI component.
Using both @mui/material-nextjs/v13-appRouter and @mui/material-nextjs/v14-appRouter

Edit: I added @emotion/styled back into package.json since after running npm update I got an error saying it was missing.
Edit2: The fix was using the correct syntax for creating a theme. Seems like a very odd error to throw for what was just a theme misconfiguration. Thanks @Lucepall

Hi, may I asked you which Node version you are using?, I've tried to replicate the issue by adding all of your dependecies and the MUI setup configuration for "Next.js integration" but I'm not getting the error.
I'm using node v20.11.1 and npm v9.6.7. I could open StackBlitz project if the error persists,

@Lucepall, my Node version was 18.18.0, I just upgraded to 20.12.2 with no changes. npm version = 10.2

@Lucepall, I also tried creating a new next project from scratch (I copied my src folder over) and added dependencies one by one and eventually got to the same runtime error. How did you create a new project and install mui?

I've run,npx create-next-app@latest, then npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled a finally copy your list of depencies and run npm i .

I followed the steps you provided and was able to get a new app running with the AppRouterCacheProvider and ThemeProvider in the root layout.tsx. However, once I added an MUI component to the root page.tsx I got a similar runtime undefined type error. I also tried adding a custom component to the root page.tsx instead of raw MUI with no change in outcome. Did your app from scratch add any MUI components to the page? Thank you for the help so far!

Hi, I've created a repo with all the packages, and I've also added a simple form using MUI components. If you encounter any errors, please feel free to open a pull request for debugging. https://github.com/fellowstack/next-mui-theme-provider

Thank you for providing the git repo, I was able to track down my problem! I was not creating my theme correctly. I made a POJO instead of using the createtheme() function. Thank you very much for the help, I really appreciate it. If you want, you can create an answer then I can accept it. Otherwise I will create an answer tomorrow.

yeahh that great! I'm glad you solved it. Let me create the answer with including the repo, and the versions I'm using and you can also add the fixing part! Thanks

I've updated my answer. I've just left the theme part and the repository pointing to the theme config.

Check how your theme is created, here is an example:
"use client";
        
import { Roboto } from 'next/font/google';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const roboto = Roboto({
  weight: ['300', '400', '500', '700'],
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: 'swap',
});

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: roboto.style.fontFamily,
  },
});

export default theme;

